# awk: only print lines when all words are matched by some words in an array

Tags: awk, grep

I don't know enough about `awk` to accomplish what I would like to accomplish here. Maybe something else should be used? I have two csv files. One is very large and has nearly 500,000 lines and another one may have anywhere between 1,000 and 30,000 lines.

File 1 contains a list of sentences in the 3rd column.

File 2 contains a list of frequently used words in the 1st column.

How can I print only lines from File 1 that only contain full words that are in the list in File 2? This is probably pretty basic. I'm sorry if it's been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer.

File 1:

```
239493     eng     Ice is cold.
393939     eng     Freshwater turns to ice when the temperature drops below zero degrees centigrade.
383822     eng     Lava is hot.
330209     eng     Lava is very hot.
330207     eng     Bacon is tasty.
```

File 2:

```
ice
lava
cold
is
hot
bacon
narwhale
midnight
```

Output:

```
239493     eng     Ice is cold.
383822     eng     Lava is hot.
```

Comment: How come this line (`Ice is cold.` ) is coming in output? `Ice` word is not matched in `file2`.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention. Thank you. I edited the post.

Comment: Why isn't `Lava is very hot` in the expected output?

Comment: very is not in file 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Perl:

```
perl -lane '
  BEGIN { $x = pop; %h = map { chomp; lc $_ => 1 } <>; @ARGV = $x }
  print if scalar @F - 2 == scalar grep { $_ } map { s/\W//g; $h{lc $_} } @F[2..$#F]
' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
239493     eng     Ice is cold.
383822     eng     Lava is hot.
```

---

Using AWK:

```
awk '
  FNR==NR { a[tolower($1)]++; next }
  { r = $0; for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/\W/,"",$i); if (tolower($i) in a) c++ } }
  c + 2 == NF { print r }
  c = 0
' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
239493     eng     Ice is cold.
383822     eng     Lava is hot.
```

Comment: Both of these scripts work beautifully and I will be putting them to a lot of work. Thank you!

Comment: whats `\W` ? Cant find any info on it ?

Comment: @Jidder: `\W` will match any non-word character (alphanumeric or underscore). [Regex](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html). Thinking more about it, the OP may also want to add another substitution to handle special cases like hyphenated words, but hasn't explained how to treat them, if they exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[toupper($1)]++;next} {f=3; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){ if(toupper($i) in a){f++} } if(f==NF){print $0}}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Output was either blank or ������������������

Comment: It is working with your sample inputs. Can you tell me no of lines are in file2  and file1.

Comment: With sample inputs it worked, but when adding another sentence it did not. Will return: Bacon is tasty.

Comment: The File1 I'm actually working with has 441,845 lines and 6 columns. The File2 I'm working with has 1,000 lines.

Comment: @user3800478, Make sure that you are passing `file2` as a first argument and `file1` as a second argument to `awk`.